# What might be the best loss function when target is a gaussian label?

Tags: keras, regression, object-detection, tensorflow2.0, loss-function

I have a simple CNN with the inputs as

- Cropped grayscale patches of size MxN centered on the object of interest. The intensity of each patch is rescaled to [0, 1].
- Target Gaussian label of the same size MXN with values ranging
  in [5.0155e-173, 1]. This label is kept fixed throughout the training.

[image: Target Gaussian label with (5.0155e-173, 1) as (min, max)]

The goal is to learn the target label and use the learned model to detect the object in a test image. I am using Adam optimizer with various loss functions such as `categorical_crossentropy`, `mean_squared_error`, and `mean_absolute_error` but training halts soon probably due to the low values returned by all these loss functions (vanishing gradients?). Increasing the batch size from 1 to 16~32 sometimes helps in completing the iteration but gives undesired outcomes at test time.

Is it because the loss function is too sensitive to the lower values in the target and even treats them as outliers hence steering the whole learning process in the wrong direction?

I'll be grateful for your help in fixing the loss function in such a scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best choice here is to use some probability ditribution pseudo-distance, the first choice that came to my mind is to use Kullback-Leiber Divergence, it is already implemented in pytorch and keras( see [kldivloss](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#kldivloss and [keras](https://keras.io/losses/#kullback_leibler_divergence)) Other famous ditances may include Jesnsen-Shanon divergence and Earth-Mover distance (This the same distance thatwas used in [WGAN](https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.07875)